# Why the maximum resolution available is 640x480 if my laptop has a 1280x800p?

Tags: laptop, screen, display-resolution, xrandr

I've just installed Linux Ubuntu on my laptop and the screen looks very strange because all the margins are quite big. I know that I can do all the xrandr commands(eg. add more, newmode, output...) But the problem is that the maximum resolution available is 640 x 480 while the laptop's screen is 1280 x 800.
When I set a different mode for the default screen, it says that the configuration failed, and I'm sure it has to do with the maximum resolution. [Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATj74.jpg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was just:

```
xrandr|grep connect
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more how this command solved the problem?

Comment: It just added the maxiumum screen resolution to the ones available in the xrandr and then I did what all the videos in YouTube say setting the new resolution as the default one.